# Extend class with specific methods from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extend my custom class 'Test' with a few of the output functions contained within the 'logging' module. I have a custom logging level called 'print' which is causing me issues. I have tried multiple methods and each has some drawback. Is there any other methods that would be better that I am missing.

I want to be able to use vars() on the object while and only print out the attributes that aren't logging methods.

This method works but prints out the 'print' method (which I don't want)

```
#Test.py
logger = logging.getLogger('console')

class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       self._some_obj = True
       self.print= logger.print

#main.py
vars(Test()) # Prints {'_some_obj':True,'print': <bound method Logger.printof <Logger console (PRINT)>>}
```

This method correctly only prints out only correct attributes but overwrites default print in the process

```
#Test.py
logger = logging.getLogger('console')

class Test:
   print = logger.print # Overwrites default print
   def __init__(self):
       self._some_obj = True

#main.py
vars(Test()) # Prints {'_some_obj':True}
```

This method also works but doesn't seem very pythonic. Since I will be doing this to alot of functions it will take up alot of space and I have also had issues passing through optional parameters

```
#Test.py
logger = logging.getLogger('console')

class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       self._some_obj = True

  def print(msg):
      logger.print(msg)

#main.py
vars(Test()) # Prints {'_some_obj':True}
```

Comment: where are the `def` in your inits? :(

Comment: Woops. Missed that. Fixed

Comment: Why don’t you inherit `logging.Logger` class?